# Comparing two lists in Python

Tags: python

So I have an assignment and here are the requirements,

*For this program, we'll be generating more statistics about lists. The program will work with one list that the user inputs and the other is a set list of words. The program will count how many times each of the words from the set list exists in the input list, and display these results.*

Some other things to note is that I cannot use other data structures such as Python's dictionary.

Here is a rough draft of what I have so far,

```
def main():
    setlist=['One', 'Two', 'Three']
    words=input('Input words')
    inputlist=getlist(words)
    print(inputlist)
    counts,word=comparelist(setlist,inputlist)
    print(counts)
    print(word)

def getlist(words):
    list1=[]
    count=0
    for i in words.split():
        j=[i,count]
        count+=1
        list1.append(j)
    return list1

def comparelist(setlist,inputlist):
    count=0
    for words in setlist:
        list2words=words
        if list2words in inputlist:
            count+=1
            return count, words
        else:
            count=count+0
            return count, words

main()
```

I'm still fairly new to Python, (about a few weeks practice) and I'm kinda stumped. I know it has to do with the third function but I seem to can't get it to work. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Also, this is my first question I have asked on Stackoverflow, so any other recommendation with question etiquette would also be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What has to do with the third function?

Comment: I would recommend giving the outline of a test case you tried. So give an example input, the expected output for that input, and the actual output when you run it through your program :)

Comment: Can we use modules like [collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I count the occurrences of a list item in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood you correctly (count how many times each of the words from the set list exists in the input list), but this might help:

```
# Two lists to compare:    
list1 = ['Words', 'in', 'list', 'one']
list2 = ['Words', 'in', 'list', 'two']

# Make a new list of all the common elements and take the length:
print len([i for i in list1 if i in list2])

>>> 3
```

Sorry if I misunderstood. If you want a shorthand way at least, then list comprehensions are useful. 
The following is probably what you wanted:

```
list1 = ['Words', 'list', 'oh', 'one']
list2 = ['Words', 'list', 'list', 'two']

print [list2.count(i) for i in list1]

>>> [1, 2, 0, 0]
```

An easy way to understand whats going on here; firstly `for i in list1` loops of the items in list1. Then `list2.count(i)` counts the number of occurances of each of these items in list2. The `[ ]` means a new list is returned, hence the output in list format `[1, 2, 0, 0]`

Comment: I believe OP wants a count of how many times _each_ word in the set list appears in the input list.

Comment: I did not downvote you but I question how useful this will be to the OP. They are new to Python and have clearly stated that their question is an assignment question. I am not sure just giving the OP a pythonic answer is very helpful...

Comment: I see, I misunderstood. I don't think it is ever too soon to try and learn about list comprehensions, they are one of the best features of python after all :)

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems to be coming from a misunderstanding of what the `return` keyword does!

`return` passes a value back to the caller of the function and **exits** the function. That is, once you call `return` the rest of the function does not run!

Try fixing your code with this in mind and let me know if you have more trouble :)